# How to avoid dependency cycles in a WPF client-server application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hello i'm new to this forum and i'm looking for some help.
I am developing a WPF application, essentially the app allows users to pick file from filesystem and send the full path to a python server as well as other sort of communications i'll have to implement.

I split my WPF app into three parts. The WPF GUI itself, a set of controllers that handle the client - server communications and a third component called "Controller Access Layer" which manage the whole data flow between GUI and Controllers.

I don't want GUI and Controller to communicate directly but to have an intermediate structure.In Visual Studio i have three project called GUI, Client, CAL(Contoller access layer). GUI and Client have a reference to CAL since they both need a CAL object, but in order to make CAL access Controllers and GUI i should reference these from here.

If i try to add a reference to CAL against GUI and Client i get a dependency error. I've read about this problem and the bad design behind it, so i'm wondering if my desing is conceptually correct and how i could avoid a dependency cycle in this context.

```
public class CAL
{
    // CAL Object shared between projects
    public static CAL ControlAccessLayer { get; } = new CAL();
    Dictonary<string,BaseController> ListController {get; set;}
 }
```

The above code is the CAL class, as you can see this class has a Dictionary of BaseController objects. Another thing i'm not sure of is the way i shared the CAL object between projects, basically i set a static CAL object accessible from the other two projects.
I'm not a professional designer and new to this field, i would like to have some advice.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why would CAL need to have a reference to the UI layer? This part doesn't make sense. Usually UI just references one layer below (business layer or whatever you want to call it). Also, what does the CAL layer do, exactly? It contains Viewmodels?

Comment: i would suggest reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx it will give you a better understanding of MVVM which is a requirement of WPF binding working correctly

Comment: *I don't want GUI and Controller to communicate directly but to have an intermediate structure.* But it seems you are using a singleton, `CAL.ControlAccessLayer` to interact between layers, and this is a bad idea which only promotes tighter coupling and makes testing/code reuse harder.

Answer (score 1):

Move the components that are used in both projects to a seperate project (xyz.common). If the implementation for example should be in CAL, then define an interface in the common project that you use in the client layer and implenment the interface in the CAL project.

That's how we do it in my current project where we also share some objects in the client and backend.